# ASIHTTP Request how to handle timeout with account registration

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

Sometimes when a user creates an account with my iPhone app the network times out. On a really bad edge connection the request times out, but the server did receive the request and processes the registration.

Now, because the user got a timeout error, they will attempt to register again, but since the account was created successfully (and because of the timeout there was no "status" "success" on the client end) the user will now get a "username/email" already registered message.

Sorry if this sounds confusing, but does anyone know a work around for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers are really about handling this situation in a way that doesn't confuse the user too much, rather than avoiding it - you can never completely avoid getting in to this situation. So try things like:

- Email the user to tell them their registration has been successful
- Return a special code if you get an attempt to register an account with identical details/password to an existing one, and then just login to that account instead of giving an 'already registered' error.

Comment: Yes, I took your advice and added a special case to bypass registration and go straight to login. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry if this sounds confusing, but does anyone know a work around for this issue?

Yes: use a longer timeout.

Several ten seconds are completely fine.

Like you've witnessed yourself, timeouts in the mobile context have to be pretty long — program accordingly.